# Implicit conversions not considered in overload resolution?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

I'm trying to wrap a type (outside of my control) so that it would seamlessly appear to implement an interface (also outside of my control).

Given these defintions

```
// External types. Not changable.
class Foo {
    public int I { get; set; }
    public int J { get; set; }
}
interface IGenerateSignature {
    string Generate();
}
```

I would like to use a `Foo` instance to call a method with an `IGenerateSignature` parameter:

```
void Test() {
    var foo = new Foo { I = 1, J = 2 };
    GetSignature(foo);
}

void GetSignature(IGenerateSignature sig) {
    Console.Write(sig.Generate());
}
```

I tried creating an intermediary struct like this:

```
struct FooSignaturizer : IGenerateSignature {
    private readonly Foo _foo;
    public FooSignaturizer(Foo f) {
        _foo = f;
    }
    public static implicit operator FooSignaturizer(Foo f) {
        return new FooSignaturizer(f);
    }
    public string Generate() {
        return _foo.I + ":" + _foo.J;
    }
}
```

But for some reason overload resolution fails to find the conversion from `Foo` to `FooSignaturizer`, and I get a "Cannot convert" compiler error. If I manually add a cast, `GetSignature((FooSignaturizer) foo)`, it works. However, I need to also add support for the `Bar` and `Qux` types, with `BarSignaturizer` and `QuxSignaturizer`, so the cast won't work for those cases.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why is `FooSignaturizer` a struct and not a class?

Comment: Have you tried creating an implicit cast to the interface type instead?

Comment: @OmriAharon: If I get this to work, it will be used in a quite performance critical part of the code base, with very many allocations. It was suggested that a struct would possibly be allocated on the stack instead, reducing the load on the garbage collector. This is partly a test to see if that is actually true in "real world" cases.

Comment: @juharr: I don't think you can do an implicit cast to an interface.

Comment: @juharr: As far as I know it is not possible? Please enlighten me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Given Rawling's comment below, perhaps your solution might be to have your `xSignaturizer` implementations implement and interface `ISignaturizer` that has a `CastToIGenerateSignature` method? Then you could something like `GetSignature(((ISignaturizer)foo).CastToIGenerateSignature())`?

Comment: @carlpett I've never tried it, but just did and you cannot do an implicit cast to an interface because it must match the enclosing type.

Comment: @MattBurland: I'm not sure I follow?

Comment: @carlpett: See my (completely untested) answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per 7.5.3.1 of the C# spec, only implicit conversions from argument expression to parameter type are considered.

> **7.5.3.1 Applicable function member**
>
> A function member is said to be an ***applicable function member*** with respect to an argument list A when all of the following are true:
>
> - Each argument in `A` corresponds to a parameter in the function member declaration as described in §7.5.1.1, and any parameter to which no argument corresponds is an optional parameter.
> - For each argument in `A`, the parameter passing mode of the argument (i.e., value, `ref`, or `out`) is identical to the parameter passing mode of the corresponding parameter, and
>
>   - for a value parameter or a parameter array, an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from the argument to the type of the corresponding parameter, or
>   - for a `ref` or `out` parameter, the type of the argument is identical to the type of the corresponding parameter. After all, a `ref` or `out` parameter is an alias for the argument passed.

What you have here isn't an implicit conversion from `Foo` to `IGenereateSignature`, it's a wrapper.

As an explanation for this behaviour, you can't exect the compiler to go though every implementation of `IGenerateSignature` in scope to see whether it has an implicit conversion to/from `Foo`. What if there was more than one?

---

In terms of how you can achieve this for `Foo`, `Bar` and `Qux`...

What you're trying to achieve, one call to `GetSignature(fooOrBarOrQux)`, isn't possible, because (based on your description of `Foo`) you can't have one variable that can be a `Foo` *or* a `Bar` *or* a `Qux` at compile time - they're unrelated. You'll always need three call sites, so there's no reason not to have three slightly-different conversions (wrapper class or overloaded method call or something) for the three cases.

... unless you use `dynamic`?

Comment: I actually tried reading that paragraph before posting, but couldn't really make sense of it :( But your explanation was good, thanks :)

Comment: @carlpett Yeah, the spec can get pretty heavy in places, but it really is an interesting read whenever you have some time spare.

Answer (score 1):

Rawling's answer gives a good explanation of why you have the problem. Since you can't fix this with implicit conversion, you could try extension methods to convert all types to `IGenerateSignature` like this:

```
void Test() {
    var foo = new Foo { I = 1, J = 2 };
    GetSignature(foo.AsIGenerateSignature());
}

void GetSignature(IGenerateSignature sig) {
    Console.Write(sig.Generate());
}

public static class GenerateSignatureExtensions
{
    public static IGenerateSignature AsIGenerateSignature(this IGenerateSignature me)
    {
        return me;
    }
    public static IGenerateSignature AsIGenerateSignature(this Foo me)
    {
        return new FooSignaturizer(me);
    }
    public static IGenerateSignature AsIGenerateSignature(this Bar me)
    {
        return new BarSignaturizer(me);
    }
    //....
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Rawling's answer gives a great explanation of the why you are having a problem. As to how to achieve what you want. I might consider something like this:

```
public interface ISignaturizer
{
    IGenerateSignature ToSignaturizer();
}

struct FooSignaturizer : IGenerateSignature, ISignaturizer{
    private readonly Foo _foo;
    public FooSignaturizer(Foo f) {
        _foo = f;
    }

    public string Generate() {
        return _foo.I + ":" + _foo.J;
    }

    public IGenerateSignature ToSignaturizer()
    {
        return (IGenerateSignature)this;
    }
}
```

Now `BarSignaturizer` and `QuxSignaturizer` can implement the same interface. And then you can do:

```
GetSignature(((ISignaturizer)fooOrBarOrQux).ToSignaturizer());
```

Which isn't quite as elegant, but *I think* should accomplish what you need.